# Using a DLL with C interface in Java (for Android)

Tags: android, dll

I was looking into writing an app for Android platform that would (hopefully) use a DLL with a C interface.  The only way to grab information from the server is through this API.  Is this even possible?  If so, could anyone give me a point in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I was looking into writing an app for Android platform that would (hopefully) use a DLL with a C interface.

"DLL" is a Windows term. You cannot use a Windows DLL on Android. You will need C code that can work on Linux, as Android is a Linux-based operating system.

> The only way to grab information from the server is through this API. Is this even possible?

Is it possible to create a C library for use on Android? Yes. See the [Native Development Kit (NDK)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).

Is it possible to create a server that can only be accessed by some C library? Probably not without a lot of work, if that server is accessible from the Internet. Anybody can try hitting that server, or can reverse-engineer your library, or can perform packet inspection on your library-to-server communications.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?

Disclaimer: I have used in on Linux and (it works) but not on android.