# using dll library in android application

Tags: java, c#, android, dll

I have a dll C# Libraries and want to use it through my android app, I managed to run it through java but it didn't work through android, the way I used and the Exception raised is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214702/couldnt-load-library-from-loader), but I found through searching that this way won't work with android, also I found a lot of questions about that issue but didn't got any suitable answer (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445127/using-a-dll-with-c-interface-in-java-for-android), ...etc), So, I just want a clear answer, can I or can't? and if I can using any work around, How ?

Comment: but there is a chance of using it with Xamarin Android.

Comment: Check Xamarin. You might be able to. Not sure though

Comment: I know Xamarin, but it's a hybrid development technology, and in my case I had already write the whole app using Native development and the app is completed and just want to add a new module inside my app using this dll files

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat then you cant!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic-link library (also written unhyphenated), or DLL, is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows

Android is a mobile operating system (OS) based on the Linux kernel and currently developed by Google.

So no, you cant. Teoretically in some kind of VM, still - no.

Comment: vote-up for straight reasonable answer, just waiting to see if there is someone else that has a kind of solution to my problem.